# Old project running slowly on iOS 5

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

I have an old app I made for myself that I haven't used in a few months. Recently, I got a new iPhone 4 with iOS 5 on it.

EDIT: need to clear up some confusion
Device: iPhone4 running iOS5
Xcode: 4.2
Architectures : armv6
Base SDK iOS5 (Can this be changed?)
Build Active Arch Only : No

In the past I used to run the app on both an iPhone 4 & 3gs running iOS 4.2. It worked great then.

EDIT2: I installed Xcode 3.2.6 and build the project, installed it to the phone, and it build perfectly and ran fast as you would expect, no crashes. This really blows my mind... no bad_exec crashes, no lag, no failure to connect to web services due to timeouts.

Using the latest Xcode I changed the settings for the project to build for armv6 since one of the libraries included in the project is an armv6 lib and will not build for armv7.

After installing and using the app, I've noticed it's very slow and sluggish, and seems to have trouble doing any network related tasks.

There are also some bad_exec crashes in places where it never crashed before (when setting some variables from convenience methods); I cannot see any problem to indicate why it would crash in these places, especially since there were no crashes when building and using XCode 3.x and iPhone 3GS/4 a few months ago.

Is there some kind of issue going on with iOS 5 and building for armv6?

Comment: Can you post some code and output from a crash?  iOS5 does run more slowly on a 3G than iOS4 and earlier, so that part is pretty much to be expected.  Profiling might help.

Comment: did you add armv7 architecture to project settings?

Comment: @NeverBe no, because it will not compile with armv7 since I have a lib that's armv6 only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Removed all warnings tried lots of other things and it always ran slow and crashed.

Moved back to the oldest version of Xcode I could find and it solved all the problems. App compiled, worked perfect and is now accepted agian on the App Store.

Answer (score 1):

iOS 5 has many many differences from iOS 3, so if you compile old code against iOS 5 it is not going to work right out of the box. So I'd suggest that the issue has nothing to do with armv6, but rather with iOS 5, which is not backwards compatible. Of course, in your very vague question you don't give any code or any example of an actual crash along with the log, so it's impossible to be specific in an answer. But basically my suggestion is that if you want to compile an iOS 3 project against iOS 5 you must expect to rewrite some code.

Comment: One thing to specifically check for are deprecation warnings.

Comment: I installed Xcode 3.2.6 and build the project, installed it to the phone, and it build perfectly and ran fast as you would expect, no crashes. This really blows my mind... no bad_exec crashes, no lag, no failure to connect to web services due to timeouts.

Comment: Yes, but the last iOS SDK available for 3.2.6 was 4.3. So, assuming that's what you used, you're still linked against iOS 4.3. That is going to give a different result from what happens you're linked against iOS 5. So all you're doing now is repeating what you said earlier. Xcode 3.2.6 is not what's making the difference here; it's that you've reverted to your earlier build.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to do Product → Analyze and fix all warnings.